# Is it possible to have a div not collapse as the viewport width gets smaller?

Tags: css

Obviously, I could set the width property, but the div contains p elements which determine its width.

I could pull this value from the web inspector under calculated values and just enter it in manually but I wanted a more elegant solution.

```css
#mi_control {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
.menu_bottom {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
  <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Foo &copy;</p>
  <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</p>
  <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
  <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
  <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
</div>
```

The calculated width in this case is `341px` as shown by Chrome Inspector.

Comment: Did my answer ever end up working out for you?

Comment: `whitespace: nowrap` works on all inline elements, so if your `div` is `display: inline-block`, then it will work on the `div` too!

Comment: Here's the [MDN entry for white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) - the "affects divs with display inline block" part was just from my experience with `inline-block`.

Comment: Dear cade-galt, I noticed that you revoked my answer's "accepted" status today. We both lose reputation when that happens, so is there anything I can do to improve my answer and earn that status back from you? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To prevent text in the div from collapsing further in size and the text from wrapping, use the `white-space: nowrap` CSS rule on the div.

**Working Live Demo:**

```css
#mi_control{
  display: inline-block;
  position:  relative;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
  <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Arcmarks &copy; </p>
  <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About (more random text added here to increase div width more random text added here to increase div width more random text added here to increase div width)</p>
  <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
  <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
  <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/hcfbvcxk/1/

Comment: I need the p elements themselves not to wrap, not the just text in the p elements -  jsfiddle.net/hcfbvcxk/3

Comment: @cadegalt To prevent the p elements themselves from wrapping, you can set `display: inline-block;` on them instead of `float: left`: https://jsfiddle.net/hcfbvcxk/4/